# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error while doing INSERT INTO on Oracle APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I am creating a database of employees, clients, books, copies and rentals, using object-relational oracle database (Oracle Apex). I have a table of people with polymorphism, accepting both employees and clients. I am getting an error, namely: "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis " when trying to insert a client into the people's table. I really don't know why. Could anyone help me?
The error occurs in the insert bellow:

```
insert into pessoa_tb_or values(
cliente_typ(7, 'CLIENTE JUNIOR', 1, to_date('01/01/2020'), telefones_typ('9999-9999', '9999-8888'), 
locacoes_nt_typ((1, to_date('01/01/2022'), (select ref(e) from exemplar_tb_or e where cod_exemplar = 1) ), (2, to_date('01/05/2022'), (select ref(e) from exemplar_tb_or e where cod_exemplar = 2) ) )))
```

Here is my complete code and the database requirements specification (in portuguese).
[database specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee1Hx.png)
The rules for this assignment are:
The schema must contain object types, object tables, hierarchy, REF data type, nested table, VARRAY, and integrity constraints. Insert at least 5 objects in each object table.

`

```
create type livro_typ as object(
    cod_livro int,
    titulo varchar2(50),
    autor varchar2(50)
)

create type exemplar_typ as object(
    cod_exemplar int,
    data_compra date,
    livro ref livro_typ
)

create type pessoa_typ as object(
    cpf int,
    nome varchar2(50)
)not final

create type funcionario_typ under pessoa_typ(
    cod_funcionario int,
    turno varchar2(20)
)

create type telefones_typ as varray(3) of varchar2(20)


create type locacao_typ as object(
    cod_locacao int,
    data_aluguel date,
    exemplar_livro ref exemplar_typ
)

create type locacoes_nt_typ as table of locacao_typ

create type cliente_typ under pessoa_typ(
    cod_cliente int,
    data_cadastro date,
    telefones telefones_typ,
    alugueis locacoes_nt_typ
)

create table pessoa_tb_or of pessoa_typ(
    primary key(cpf),
    nome not null
)

create table livro_tb_or of livro_typ(
   primary key(cod_livro),
   titulo not null,
   autor not null
)

create table exemplar_tb_or of exemplar_typ(
   primary key(cod_exemplar),
   data_compra not null,
   livro not null
)


insert into pessoa_tb_or values(pessoa_typ(1, 'PESSOA JOAO'))
insert into pessoa_tb_or values(funcionario_typ(2, 'FUNCIONARIO PEDRO', 1, 'MANHA'))
insert into pessoa_tb_or values(funcionario_typ(3, 'FUNCIONARIO HENRIQUE', 2, 'MANHA'))
insert into pessoa_tb_or values(funcionario_typ(4, 'FUNCIONARIO LAURA', 3, 'TARDE'))
insert into pessoa_tb_or values(funcionario_typ(5, 'FUNCIONARIO LUIZA', 4, 'TARDE'))
insert into pessoa_tb_or values(funcionario_typ(6, 'FUNCIONARIO LETICIA', 5, 'NOITE'))

insert into livro_tb_or values(livro_typ(1, 'COMPUTACAO PARA LEIGOS', 'HENRIQUE FEITOSA'))
insert into livro_tb_or values(livro_typ(2, 'BANCO DE DADOS PARA LEIGOS', 'HENRIQUE FEITOSA'))
insert into livro_tb_or values(livro_typ(3, 'APRENDIZAGEM DE MAQUINA PARA LEIGOS', 'MARIA BRAGA'))
insert into livro_tb_or values(livro_typ(4, 'MATEMATICA PARA LEIGOS', 'MARIA BRAGA'))
insert into livro_tb_or values(livro_typ(5, 'FISICA PARA LEIGOS', 'FERNANDO LIMA'))

insert into exemplar_tb_or values(exemplar_typ(1, to_date('01/01/2020'), (select ref(l) from livro_tb_or l where cod_livro = 1) ))
insert into exemplar_tb_or values(exemplar_typ(2, to_date('01/01/2021'), (select ref(l) from livro_tb_or l where cod_livro = 2) ))
insert into exemplar_tb_or values(exemplar_typ(3, to_date('01/01/2022'), (select ref(l) from livro_tb_or l where cod_livro = 3) ))
insert into exemplar_tb_or values(exemplar_typ(4, to_date('01/01/2019'), (select ref(l) from livro_tb_or l where cod_livro = 4) ))
insert into exemplar_tb_or values(exemplar_typ(5, to_date('01/01/2019'), (select ref(l) from livro_tb_or l where cod_livro = 5) ))





insert into pessoa_tb_or values(
    cliente_typ(7, 'CLIENTE JUNIOR', 1, to_date('01/01/2020'), telefones_typ('9999-9999', '9999-8888'), 
    locacoes_nt_typ((1, to_date('01/01/2022'), (select ref(e) from exemplar_tb_or e where cod_exemplar = 1) ), (2, to_date('01/05/2022'), (select ref(e) from exemplar_tb_or e where cod_exemplar = 2) ) )
))
```

`
The problem occurs only in this last insert.

I already tried creating a table for clients only, and the same error still occurs.
I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested table type, but you're missing the object types for the elements of that:

```
insert into pessoa_tb_or values(
cliente_typ(7, 'CLIENTE JUNIOR', 1, to_date('01/01/2020'), telefones_typ('9999-9999', '9999-8888'), 
locacoes_nt_typ(
  locacao_typ(1, to_date('01/01/2022'), (select ref(e) from exemplar_tb_or e where cod_exemplar = 1)),
  locacao_typ(2, to_date('01/05/2022'), (select ref(e) from exemplar_tb_or e where cod_exemplar = 2))
)))
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M6tya0mU?hide=65532)

---

Incidentally, `to_date('01/01/2022')` relies on the session NLS settings. It would be better to specify the format with `to_date('01/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')`, or more simply to use a date literal with `date '2022-01-01'`:

```
insert into pessoa_tb_or values(
cliente_typ(7, 'CLIENTE JUNIOR', 1, date '2020-01-01', telefones_typ('9999-9999', '9999-8888'), 
locacoes_nt_typ(
  locacao_typ(1, date '2022-01-01', (select ref(e) from exemplar_tb_or e where cod_exemplar = 1)),
  locacao_typ(2, date '2022-05-01', (select ref(e) from exemplar_tb_or e where cod_exemplar = 2))
)))
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p6VesBXr?hide=1048512)

Comment: You solved the problem! Well noted! I am also very thankful for the additional feedback! I couldn't upvote due to my beginner reputation. I really appreciate your response! You provided a great help